# How to detect screenshots with React Native (both Android and iOS)

Tags: react-native, screenshot, react-native-ios

I am trying to detect if a user takes a screenshot while using a smartphone app that I have built. I am building my project with React Native.

I have been told that I can possibly prevent screenshots for Android but not for iOS. but can I still detect whether a user attempts to take a screenshot so that I can at least send a warning via `Alert`?

Thanks in advance

I tried `react-native-screenshot-detector` but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

you can use this package it supports android&ios screenshot detecting [react-native-detector](https://github.com/AzizAK/react-native-detector)

```
import {
  addScreenshotListener,
  removeScreenshotListener,
} from 'react-native-detector';

// ...
React.useEffect(() => {
  const userDidScreenshot = () => {
    console.log('User took screenshot');
  };
  const listener = addScreenshotListener(userDidScreenshot);
  return () => {
    removeScreenshotListener(listener);
  };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no package for it currently.